# Removing Null Square Brackets from Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe in which some column contain empty sqaure brackets like below

**Code**

```
data = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[5,3,5,6], C=[['man','talk'],['bar'],[],['bat','cat','mat']]))
```

**DataFrame**

```
    A   C
0   5   [man, talk]
1   3   [bar]
2   5   []
3   6   [bat, cat, mat]
```

I need to remove the rows containing empty square bracket

**Required Dataframe**

```
    A   C
0   5   [man, talk]
1   3   [bar]
2   6   [bat, cat, mat]
```

I tried `data = data[data["C"].str.contains("[]") == False]` but this is giving me error `error: unterminated character set at position 0` . How to remove all those rows from a dataframe.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the length of the lists with [`str.len`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) and slice using a boolean array when it is greater than 0:

```
data[data['C'].str.len().gt(0)]
```

or, convert to boolean (which seems to be the fastest approach):

```
data[data['C'].astype(bool)]
```

output:

```
   A                C
0  5      [man, talk]
1  3            [bar]
3  6  [bat, cat, mat]
```

Answer (score 1):

Please .str[index] and then dropna()

```
data[data['C'].str[0].notna()]



 A                C
0  5      [man, talk]
1  3            [bar]
3  6  [bat, cat, mat]
```

Comment: Interesting, but note that this doesn't work if there is a list like `[np.nan]` ;)

Comment: Of course, but it's always important to point limitations ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can simply do this:

```
data[data['C'].map(lambda d: len(d)) > 0]

   A                C
0  5      [man, talk]
1  3            [bar]
3  6  [bat, cat, mat]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data.loc[data.C.apply(len)!=0]

  A                C
0  5      [man, talk]
1  3            [bar]
3  6  [bat, cat, mat]
```